# What is the meaning of "constructed" in the following text? What is "they" referring to in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, pronouns, ambiguity

Informational and statistical visualizations engender the rhetoric
of clarity, precision, and fact, though "they" are, of course, constructed interpretations.

Comment: See also [ell.se]

Comment: I assume the scare quotes (if in the original) are used as an ad-hoc instruction to disregard the 'pronoun refers to nearest [reasonable?] noun group' convention. It's poorly written.

Comment: The scare quotes are not in the original text, I have added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'They' refers to 'Informational and statistical visualisations'  - which means 'ways of presenting information graphically'.

'Constructed' means that the said 'informational and statistical visualisations' have been *made* by somebody - and therefore presumably are subject to that person's 'construction method', perspective, foibles, viewpoint, mood, desired effect, and way of using the data - to create a 'picture' of it.

The 'picture' takes on the *appearance* of 'clarity, precision, and fact' - perhaps because it is 'physicalised' - however it still is merely an interpretation - a point of view, of the data.